# VBScript: Extracting data from a spreadsheet to import it into a config file

Tags: excel, vbscript, config, cisco

A little background on what I need assistance with. I am currently working on a project that is requiring the configuration of over 500 Cisco 2911 Routers. Part of the job is to take a premade config file provided by our customer and make it location specific. That involves changing the hostname and the second and third IP octets.

I have recently made a script that will actually configure the device but now I need to make another script that will make the changes in the default config file and save it location specific. The goal is when they launch the script, it will prompt for the location, open the config file, change the hostname, open a spreadsheet containing an IP calculator, look for the location, extract the IP from it, plug it into the necessary location, then save it location specific and allow my first script to run.

Until about a week ago I have done little to no coding for over a decade so I am rusty and my knowledge is not that great. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is too broad to get any answers here. What you need to do is make a start and post a specific question when you have a problem. The people posting answers will rarely spend more than 5 or 10 minutes on an answer - we all have a living to make - and you've just asked a question which a reasonable answer would need quite a lot of time (and more info) to answer. You've just asked 'how do I do my job?' in effect: there is an assumption that you know that. Sorry, but StackOverflow does need a more focussed question to be useful.

Comment: If the base config (generic) file is plain text, why not post some of it (without real IP address/hostnames) and structure of the spreadsheet so we can give you ideas? Say in the generic config, replace actual Router IP with `<RouterIP>`, hostname to `<RouterHostname>`, subnet to `<SubNet>` etc to have excel vba to export the config file?

Answer (score 0):

Too much to type in here but lets make it simple for you.
Do a CSV file with hostname, Interface1, IP1, Mask1, Interface2, IP2, Mask2, Location, etc..
try to put all the data that you will need for each device on a single raw on a CSV and the using python, pexpect or telnet modules and some bash you could be able to do all of that on just one script.
Will be a lot of work but at the end you will have a script that will help you on future global configs like this one for +500 devices.

Use this sites as reference:

http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/346/python-how-to-access-ssh-with-pexpect/
http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/doc/

I did one with those same tools that I mentioned and it runs commands on +1000 different cisco routers, switches and ASA and print on screen a report at the end.

Try with those tools.
Regards,